# How to concatenate an address to a string in solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, addresses, string

I am trying to find the correct way to concatenate an Ethereum address to a string in Solidity **v0.6.7**

I tried the following but it did not seem to work :

```
    function append(string a, address b) internal pure returns (string) {

    return string(abi.encodePacked(a, b));

}
```

Any point in the correct direction would be appreciated

Comment: You'll probably have to write a function that converts address to string using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is the working function :

```
function addressToString(address _address) internal pure returns(string memory) {
   bytes32 _bytes = bytes32(uint256(uint160(_address)));
   bytes memory HEX = "0123456789abcdef";
   bytes memory _string = new bytes(42);
   _string[0] = '0';
   _string[1] = 'x';
   for(uint i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
       _string[2+i*2] = HEX[uint8(_bytes[i + 12] >> 4)];
       _string[3+i*2] = HEX[uint8(_bytes[i + 12] & 0x0f)];
   }
   return string(_string);
}
```

Comment: This is to cast an address to a string, not to concatenate  (and I know you’re answering yourself)